Is using vuforia web services possible through unity?
I've been trying to create a script to add a new target to my vuforia cloud database for about a week now and I have not been able to get it to work. I keep getting HTTP 400: Bad Request despite trying so many different ways to send my HTTP POST request.
Here's what I have for my code so far:
    byte[] image = QRTexture.EncodeToPNG();
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image); 
    string jsonPayload = "{\"name\":\"" + firebaseID + "\", \"width\":32.0, \"image\":\"" + base64 + "\"}";
    string requestPath = "/targets";
    string serviceURI = url + requestPath;
    string httpAction = "POST";
    string contentType = "application/json";
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
    Debug.Log(date);

    PostNewTrackableRequest model = new PostNewTrackableRequest
    {
        name = firebaseID,
        width = 64.0,
        image = Convert.ToBase64String(image),
    };
    string requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    var headers = form.headers;
    headers["host"] = url;
    headers["date"] = date;
    headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;

    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    var contentMD5bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < contentMD5bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(contentMD5bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    string contentMD5 = sb.ToString();

    string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}", httpAction, contentMD5, contentType, date, requestPath);

    HMACSHA1 sha1 = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret_key));
    byte[] sha1Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSign);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(sha1Bytes);
    byte[] sha1Hash = sha1.ComputeHash(stream);
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Hash);

    headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("VWS {0}:{1}", access_key, signature);

    Debug.Log("<color=green>Signature: " + signature + "</color>");
    UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(serviceURI, "POST");
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "VWS "+access_key+":"+secret_key);
    request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    
    if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log("QR code uploaded successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("QR code upload failed!);
    }

I've tried so many different codes and different widths and images and names but to no avail. Is there C# Script that actually works for this?

Have you tried to send the request outside of Unity from your development machine to check if this is indeed a Unity issue? For example you could python https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

i have and it still didn't work i honestly don't know what i'm doing wrong

Have you looked at the JSON text body output? Someone had similar issues here and it boiled down to the request formatting https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/cloud-recognition/400-bad-request
